# Anypoint Studio application terminated after 12 hours

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

After running application in Anypoint Studio 7.12 in has been terminated after approximately 12 hours without any error code.
What is reason and how this behavior could be changed or any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior. Anypoint Studio is an IDE, for development. It is not meant to execute applications for extended periods of time. If you need to execute an application for more than one or two hours use a standalone Mule runtime installation or some other deployment target like CloudHub or Runtime Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

There could be plenty of reasons may not be able to tell exactly it depending on your system JVM ect.

But it's not expected behavior definitely.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is expected behavior for Anypoint Studio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).